# .VBS failing to open more than 2 tabs

Tags: vbscript

I have a number of sites that I have to monitor as part of my job. I created a .vbs (though in troubleshooting this issue, I also created and had the same problem with .js and .bat files). This file simply opens a new Internet Explorer window and then would put a new tab for each website I would need. This is the code:

```
Const navOpenInBackgroundTab = &H1000

site1 = "http://www.google.com"
site2 = "http://www.yahoo.com"
site3 = "http://www.bing.com"
site4 = "http://www.duckduckgo.com"

Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

oIE.Visible = True
oIE.Navigate2 site1
oIE.Navigate2 site2,navOpenInBackgroundTab
oIE.Navigate2 site3,navOpenInBackgroundTab
oIE.Navigate2 site4,navOpenInBackgroundTab

Set oIE = Nothing
```

Executing this file has been flawless for me and I have been able to set it to automatically run through the scheduler to automate my task monitoring until recently. Now when I run it, it only opens the first 2 tabs regardless of how many I have as part of the script.

I have been scouring the internet in search of a solution on this and haven't found anything. Is this just some Windows setting that I am going to need to seek a solution elsewhere (as Windows is technically off-topic) or is there something I could add to the file to force the command line to load more than the first two tabs?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Your script works as you want on my computer.

Comment: Thank you. I guess that is what is maddening about the whole thing. I know that it should work on my computer, but it still only loads 2. There must be some random setting somewhere that is breaking it after 2.

Comment: Try adding a `wscript.sleep 100` in or something.